# Extending NanoHTTPD

Tags: java, server, nanohttpd

I need to write a HTTP server program in Java that

- Process SOME requests (i.e, having certain parameters) to store some data sent from clients, and.
- The rest of requests show a "home" page, showing the data received from the clients.

The problem is, in the "home" page I want to show a page that uses local images or JavaScript, and I don't know how to make it work. I mean, I have seen the example in NanoHTTPD home page and it works great, but where should I place the static content (images, js) to be included in the HTML I generate as a response?

Code added as per request.

@nicomp, this example is an adaptation from the example code in https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd. The image monkey.png is not served (it appears as a broken img in the browser).

```java
public class Main extends NanoHTTPD {

    public Main() throws IOException {
        super(8080);
        start(NanoHTTPD.SOCKET_READ_TIMEOUT, false);
        System.out.println("\nRunning! Point your browsers to http://localhost:8080/ \n");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new Main();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't start server:\n" + ioe);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
        String msg = "<html><body><h1>Hello server</h1>\n";
        msg += "<img src=\"monkey.png\">";
        return newFixedLengthResponse(msg + "</body></html>\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To include static content such as images and JavaScript in the HTML response, you can create a directory within your project to store these files. Let's call it `static`.

Next, you need to serve the static content files from this directory. You can do this by creating a `StaticFileServer` class that extends the `NanoHTTPD` class and overrides the `serve()` method. In the `serve()` method, you can check if the requested URI starts with the string "/static" and if so, serve the corresponding file from the `static` directory. Here's an example:

```
import fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class StaticFileServer extends NanoHTTPD {
    private final String staticDir;

    public StaticFileServer(int port, String staticDir) {
        super(port);
        this.staticDir = staticDir;
    }

    @Override
    public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
        String uri = session.getUri();
        if (uri.startsWith("/static")) {
            String filePath = staticDir + uri.substring(7); // Remove "/static" prefix
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
                return newChunkedResponse(Response.Status.OK, getMimeType(filePath), inputStream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return newFixedLengthResponse(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND, NanoHTTPD.MIME_PLAINTEXT, "File not found");
            }
        } else {
            // Handle other requests here
        }
    }

    private String getMimeType(String filePath) {
        if (filePath.endsWith(".html")) {
            return NanoHTTPD.MIME_HTML;
        } else if (filePath.endsWith(".css")) {
            return "text/css";
        } else if (filePath.endsWith(".js")) {
            return "application/javascript";
        } else if (filePath.endsWith(".png")) {
            return "image/png";
        } else if (filePath.endsWith(".jpg") || filePath.endsWith(".jpeg")) {
            return "image/jpeg";
        } else if (filePath.endsWith(".gif")) {
            return "image/gif";
        } else {
            return NanoHTTPD.MIME_DEFAULT_BINARY;
        }
    }
}
```

In the `serve()` method, we check if the URI starts with "/static". If it does, we construct the file path by removing the "/static" prefix and appending it to the `staticDir` path. Then we open an input stream to read the file and return a `ChunkedResponse` with the file's MIME type. If the file is not found, we return a 404 Not Found response.

Now that we have our `StaticFileServer` class, we can use it to serve our static files. In your main HTTP server program, you can create an instance of the `StaticFileServer` class and pass in the port and the path to the `static` directory. Then, in the `serve()` method of your main HTTP server program, you can generate the HTML response and include references to the static files using their URLs:

```
public class MainServer extends NanoHTTPD {
    private static final int PORT = 8080;
    private static final String STATIC_DIR = "static";

    public MainServer() {
        super(PORT);
    }

    @Override
    public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
        String uri = session.getUri();
        if (uri.equals("/")) {
            // Generate HTML response with references to static files
            String responseHtml = "<html><head><title>Home</title>" +
                                  "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/static/style.css\">" +
                                  "<script src=\"/static/script.js\"></script></head>" +
                                  "<body
```